# Facebook API fetch new scrape information

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking for answers for days. If anyone could help be, that'd be great. After changing the meta tags on my site, I am trying to get facebook to refresh its cached data programatically, so that the meta tags are updated when I share the URL on Facebook. I have used the Open Graph Object Debugger [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and it works well, but I need to do this automatically. I've found a way by doing a POST like this :

```
string sUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/?id=" + Url + "&scrape=true";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);


request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

The POST seems to work well, the status returned is 200 OK. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work when I want to share my web page on Facebook. The picture, title and description is not updated.

**EDIT :** I have found that using the canonical URL works for me. Not quite sure why it would makes a difference, but it solved my problem.

Comment: If the scrape was successful, then you should get information about the properties it has read from your page back in response to your request.

Comment: It does, but when I share my URL, the data is not updated and I have the old picture and description.